# Using Fn for shortcuts on OS X impossible?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I was trying to remap the Home and End keys on my mac to Fn+Right and Fn+Left and I could find no way to do it. In fact I couldn't create or modify any shortcuts using Fn.

Is there any way to do this? I would think that it should be possible since programs like vim can use Fn for shortcuts, but maybe thats just because vim catches all keyboard input.

P.S. I was unable to find a way to do it using Library/KeyBindings/keybindings.dict

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pqrs.org's Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) [formerly known as KeyRemap4MacBook] will let you do this.